# Execute a PHP Function when a Block is used and access it's attributes

Tags: php, block-editor, wp-head

I've just build my first block using the `@wordpress/create-block package`.

Everything is working as expected however I need to access the attributes on save and place a script containing a `JSON schema` in `wp_head`. Assuming that this needs to be done in PHP, how do I access the attributes of these blocks on save?

I have tried add_filter only to find that this stores names and the innerHTML of the block and I have created a custom render file and printed the attributes only contain boolean attributes not the html attributes that contain the question and answer.

I'd rather not override `save.js` at all, I simply want to access the attributes and execute a PHP script. What am I missing here?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can put JSON schema in the body, so you could just render it as part of your block.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for your comment. If this were for the purpose of creating an FAQ page then it would register multiple FAQpage script tags inline. This doesn't sound the most efficient way of doing it.